Unable to access the help pages when loading functions using box package
I am using the box package. In my project, I have a code/functions folder, with two functions saved in there: hello.r and goodbye.r
In the code/functions folder I have a __init__.R file with the code:
#' @export
box::use(
  ./hello[...],
  ./goodbye[...],
)


When I load the functions using:
box::use(
  code/functions/hello[...],
  code/functions/goodbye[...],
)


I can access the help pages that I have defined in the .R files using roxygen tags. For example by using box::help(hello) to show the help page for the hello function...
However when I load the functions using box::use(code/functions[...]), although the function I created works, when I try to access the help pages using box::help(hello) I get  an error message saying no documentation available.
Any suggestions as to why it can't access the documentation?

Unfortunately you’ve stumbled across a known bug: https://github.com/klmr/box/issues/330 — The bug is still around because fixing it isn’t trivial (well, a quick-and-dirty fix would be almost trivial, but unfortunately it doesn’t work in the very relevant case where reexports are renamed).
